# Remove indentation of enumerate environment in enumerate environment

Tags: indentation, enumerate

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label = \textbf{Exercise \arabic*.}]
\item ajksdjkldjslasdjklasd
    \begin{enumerate}[label = \textbf{\alph*.}]
        \item ajhsdjajksdasdajksd
    \end{enumerate}

\item ajksdkasjdadsasd
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

How do I remove the indentation of the item a.? I would like to have it aligned with the item Exercise 1/2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you want one of these?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%
 \usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Exercise \arabic*.}, wide = 0pt, itemsep=1.5ex]
\item ajksdjkldjslasdjklasd
    \begin{enumerate}[label = \textbf{\alph*.},wide =0pt]
        \item ajhsdjajksdasdajksd ajhsdjajks dasdajksd ajhsdjajksd asdajksd ajhsdjajks dasdajksd dasdajksd ajhsdjajksd asdajksd ajhsdjajks dasdajksd
    \end{enumerate}

\item ajksdkasjdadsasd
\end{enumerate}
\bigskip

\begin{enumerate}[label = \textbf{Exercise \arabic*.}, wide=0pt, itemsep=1.5ex]
\item ajksdjkldjslasdjklasd
    \begin{enumerate}[label = \textbf{\alph*.},wide=0pt, labelsep=0.15em, leftmargin=*]
        \item ajhsdjajksdasdajksd ajhsdjajks dasdajksd ajhsdjajksd asdajksd ajhsdjajks dasdajksd dasdajksd ajhsdjajksd asdajksd ajhsdjajks dasdajksd
    \end{enumerate}

\item ajksdkasjdadsasd
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may add option **leftmargin=0pt** for enumii,

```
\begin{enumerate}[label = \textbf{\alph*.},leftmargin=0pt]
```

Comment: This does partially help, but it aligns just with the numbers.